# Page not found, with using angular-js, node.js, and ui-router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-ui-router

I'm following through this tutorial: https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial#introduction.
when i'm coming to the end of Beginning Node section, i'm running the command : npm start, but i'm getting error Not found when i'm opening the localhost:3000.

here's the code:
angularApp.js

```
var app = angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider',
    function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
        $stateProvider.state('home',{
            url: '/home',
            templateUrl: '/home.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl'
        });
        $stateProvider.state('posts', {
          url: '/posts/{id}',
          templateUrl: '/posts.html',
          controller: 'PostsCtrl'
        });
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('home');
}]);

app.factory('posts',[function(){
  var o = {
    posts: []
  };
  return o;
}]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope','posts',
function($scope,posts){
    $scope.title = '';
    $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
    $scope.posts = posts.posts;
    $scope.addPost = function(){
        if(!$scope.title || $scope.title === '') { return; }
        $scope.posts.push({
          title: $scope.title,
          link: $scope.link,
          upvotes: 0,
          comments: [
            {author: 'Joe', body: 'Cool post!', upvotes: 0},
            {author: 'Bob', body: 'Great idea but everything is wrong!', upvotes: 0}
          ]
        });
        $scope.title = '';
        $scope.link = '';
    };
    $scope.incrementUpvotes = function(post) {
        post.upvotes += 1;
    };

}]);

app.controller('PostsCtrl',['$scope','$stateParams','posts',
    function($scope,$stateParams,posts){
        $scope.post = posts.posts[$stateParams.id];
        $scope.addComment = function(){
          if($scope.body === '') { return; }
          $scope.post.comments.push({
            body: $scope.body,
            author: 'user',
            upvotes: 0
          });
          $scope.body = '';
        };      
    }
]);
```

index.ejs

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Flapper News</title>
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.14/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
  <script src="/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="/home.ejs">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Flapper News</h1>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
        ng-click="incrementUpvotes(post)"></span>
      {{post.upvotes}}
      <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
        <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
          {{post.title}}
        </a>
        <span ng-hide="post.link">
          {{post.title}}
        </span>
      </span>
      <span>
      <a href="#/posts/{{$index}}">Comments</a>
    </span>
    </div>
    <form ng-submit="addPost()"
      style="margin-top:30px;">
      <h3>Add a new post</h3>
     <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Title"
          ng-model="title"></input>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text"
        class="form-control"
        placeholder="Link"
        ng-model="link"></input>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
    </form>
</script>
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/posts.ejs">
  <div class="page-header">
    <h3>
      <a ng-show="post.link" href="{{post.link}}">
        {{post.title}}
      </a>
      <span ng-hide="post.link">
        {{post.title}}
      </span>
    </h3>
  </div>

  <div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments | orderBy:'-upvotes'">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up"
      ng-click="incrementUpvotes(comment)"></span>
    {{comment.upvotes}} - by {{comment.author}}
    <span style="font-size:20px; margin-left:10px;">
      {{comment.body}}
    </span>
  </div>
  <form ng-submit="addComment()"
    style="margin-top:30px;">
    <h3>Add a new comment</h3>

    <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Comment"
      ng-model="body"></input>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Post</button>
  </form>
  </script>
  <style> .glyphicon-thumbs-up { cursor:pointer } </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="flapperNews">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <ui-view></ui-view> 
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure your server is running? Could you show your server side code?

Comment: In the beginning node section, iv'e created the application files with express, and after that i added the code in that question.

Comment: I didn't touch the server side code

Comment: Did you check if the server side was working before? Don't you have any erros in the server log?

Comment: No. there are no errors out there

Comment: If you are receiving a not found error it means you are using the wrong url or the server is not serving the files, please verify.

Comment: all the routing definitions are ok (as you can see in the code), and in the code here all the routes are defined...